# Why didn't Chief Inspector Kido return to Japan?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-man-in-the-high-castle

In S4 of *The Man in the High Castle*, Chief Inspector Takeshi Kido doesn't leave with his son and Japanese colleagues like the 3-star Admiral, and remains in SF. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Takeshi Kido traded his life for his son to Yakuza. Since Yakuza had his son, he offered his allegiance to them in return for his son's life.

As he is now under Yakuza he must obey their orders. And since Yakuza had decided to stay in SF he cannot leave without their permission.

Comment: "Takeshi Kido traded his life for his son to Yakuza." What does this mean please? I can't remember the plot that well.

Comment: @Accounting: Added details: It happens at end of 4th season in episode "Fire from the Gods".

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't Yakuza operate in Japan too? if so, couldn't Kido have offered to work for them in Japan?

Comment: @Accounting: They do. But there is no depiction major of Japan.